# Why can `__init__.py` import a submodule but a test file with `from module import *` can't?

Tags: python

I have the following folder structure.

```
project/
    sandbox.py
    module/
        __init__.py
        klass.py
```

`__init__.py` has the following:

```
from klass import Klass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    'do stuff'
```

This works fine. `sandbox.py` looks like this:

```
from module import *

if __name__ == '__main__":
    'do similar stuff'
```

On the command line, while in the `project` directory:

```
$ python module/__init__.py
# things work correctly
$ python sandbox.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    from module import *
  File "/Uses/chuck/.../project/module/__init__.py, line 1 in <module>
    from klass import Klass
ImportError: No module named 'klass'
```

I *think* this might have to do with relative imports, and tried changing `from klass import Klass` to `from .klass import Klass`, but that didn't work either.

My goal is, from files outside the module, to be able to use `from module import *` or `from module import Klass`. What do I need to do?

In case it matters, this is with Python 3.5.2 under macOS within a virtual environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute path and `__main__.py` file for this:

```
from module.klass import Klass

'do stuff'
```

In `__init__.py`:

```
from .klass import Klass
```

Now you can execute it as follows:

```
$ python sandbox.py
do similar stuff
$ python -m module
do somthing
```

Comment: Can you point me to a link that will help me understand the details of how these imports should work?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html, https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/